# Приложение пытается достучаться до keycloak, но выдает ошибку 403

Tags: node.js, nginx, keycloak

Пытаюсь сделать аутентификацию через keycloak, но получаю такую ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот конфигурация моего nginx:

```
worker_processes 1;

events { 
  worker_connections 1024; 
}

http {
  sendfile on;

  server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name localhost;

    return 301 https://localhost:443;
  }

  server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name localhost;

    ssl_certificate ../ssl/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key ../ssl/private.key;

    location / {
      proxy_pass         http://app/;
      # proxy_redirect     off;
      proxy_set_header   Host $host;
      proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /api/ {
      proxy_pass         http://api/;
      # proxy_redirect     off;
      proxy_set_header   Host $host;
      proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
  }

}
```

Keycloak поднят локально командой:

```
$ docker run -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_USER=<username> -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=<password> quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:15.0.2
```

В нем создан `realm test` и `client testclient`, в котором указано:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Без NGINX, то есть когда мой фронт располагался по адресу `http://localhost:5173/`, все работало отлично.

Comment: Давно занимался, не помню, как оно работает. nginx у вас обращается к клоке по http, а web origin/redirect URIs указаны https, не факт что клоке есть дело до ваших X-*; вероятно origin самого nginx клока не пропустит.

Comment: Следовательно, скорее всего в origin вам надо добавить `localhost:8080` или указать `*`, но это не точно.

Comment: Еще есть такое, что без nginx по адресу http ://localhost:5173/login перекидывает на страницу авторизации, а по с nginx по адресу https ://localhost:443/login nginx выдает 404

Comment: Возможно, в proxy_pass стоит указать порт?

Comment: Конкретнее, ```location / { proxy_pass         http://localhost:5173/;``` , ведь скорее всего Nginx пытается проксировать туда же, на 443, или вообще на 80, а там никого нет. А кто такой Http://app/ - не знает, я так думаю, никто, включая nginx. Возможно это мета-знаничие из доков, коорое подразумевалось заменить на реальный порт..